# Open a modal page inside another modal page without closing parent modal page in oracle apex 20.1

Tags: modal-dialog, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.2

I have two modal pages not inline modal pages those are two separated pages page A and page B. Inside page A there is a link to open page B. When open page B, page A will be closed. How do I avoid it.? I open the page B with option "Redirect into page in this application". I tried "Chained" disabled. But it didn't work. May be because of they are two separated pages.

Answer (score 7):

You have to turn off this option in both dialog pages

[image]

[image]